# Is this context free language regular?

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

If I have a language  {0,1} defined by the following context-free grammar with start variable S, is it a regular language?
S→TS, S→1T, S→1S
T→TT, T→0T1, T→1T0 T→ε

Is this language regular?

It seems to me that this language cannot be regular because it is basically any combination of terminals and variables. Whereas a regular language would need to be right or left linear. Am I right, or is my thinking incorrect here? Is there a specific process anyone recommends for determining if a context-free grammar is regular?

Comment: If that grammar generated all strings of 1s and 0s, it would be regular. But it doesn't. Try generating 00100, for example. Or even 0 or 00

Comment: 00100 would be a palindrome - I thought you couldn't produce a palindrome from regular languages. So isn't the fact that is can't produce 00100 mean that it is a regular language?

Comment: Obviously you can generate palindromes from a regular language (S->00100 is a regular language). The language of all palindromes is not regular, but that doesn't help you much. Think about what your language actually is.

Comment: @blazs how does that statement contradict anything I said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language associated with the grammar is not regular. The rest of the post is concerned with a proof of this statement.

First, notice that `L(T) = {w over {0,1} | w contains equal number of 0s and 1s}`.

You can prove this easily.

*Proof idea.* `(==>)` Suppose `w` in `L(T)`. Then obviously has the same number of 0s and 1s.

`(<==)` Suppose `w` contains equal number of 0s and 1s. We show by induction that `w` is derivable from `T`. If `|w|<=2`, then it is obviously derivable from `T`. Suppose, for the inductive hypothesis, that all strings of length `k` (even length) with equal number of 0s and 1s are derivable from `T`. Let `w` be of length `k+2`. If the first and the last character of `w` match (both 0 or both 1), apply the production `T -> TT`; the first and the last parts are both derivable from `T` by the inductive hypothesis; here, we're using the obvious property that if `w[0]=w[|w|-1]` then there exists an index `i` such that `w[0..i]` and `w[i+1..|w|-1]` are both in `L(T)`, and both derivable from `T` by the inductive hypothesis. Else, if the first and the last characters of `w` don't match, use either `T -> 0T1` or `T -> 1T0`; the resulting string is of length `k` and is derivable from `T` by the inductive hypothesis. **QED.**

Now, the language of the grammar is the set of strings that can be generated by `S`. Notice that `S` generates strings (of terminals and variables) of the form `(T+1)*1T`. In other words, for any string of terminals `w` derivable by the grammar it must be the case that `S =>* α =>* w`, where `α` is in `(T+1)*1T`.

Now it should be evident that the set of all possible terminals that can be generated by `S` is characterised by the regular expression `(L(T)* + 1)*1L(T)*`. (You can arrive at this by inspecting the set of strings of terminals that can be generated from `(T+1)*1T`.)

You can simplify the expression for `L(S)`: `(L(T)+1)*1L(T)=(L(T)+1)*` because the language of `1L(T)` is a subset of the language of `(L(T)+1)^2`. Thus `L(S) = (L(T)+1)*`, the language comprised of binary strings that contain at least as many 1s as 0s.

This language *is not* regular. You can prove this using the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

*Proof*. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that `L(S)` is regular. Then, by the pumping lemma, there's `n>0` such that every `w` from `L(S)` of length at least `n` can be broken into `w=xyz` such that:

1. `|xy| <= n`,
2. `y` non-empty,
3. for all `k >= 0`, `xy^ky` in `L(S)`.

Let `w=0^n1^n` be a string of length `m=2n` from `L(S)`. (The lemma talks about *all* sufficiently long strings from `L(S)`, so we can pick any string we like and still have the properties.) Let `w=xyz` be a partitioning that exists by the lemma. Obviously, since `m=2n` and `|xy|<=n`, `y` is comprised of `0`s only (and at least one `0` since `y` is not empty).

Clearly, `xy^2z` has more zeros than ones and is thus not in `L(S)`. This contradicts the pumping lemma. Thus, `L(S)` is not regular. **QED.**

Comment: closure for regular languages only applies to languages that ARE regular, not to languages that ARE NOT regular.  In particular, the union of two non-regular languages might be regular.

Comment: Your induction step in the first proof is incorrect (or at least incomplete).  consider `001110`.  This begins and ends in `0` so you split it, but the two halves (`001` and `110`) are NOT in L(T).

Comment: @ChrisDodd thanks, that's easy to fix: it's possible to break this sort of string in suitable way. You're absolutely right about the closure properties; I'm not sure how to finish the proof for non-regularity of L(S).

Comment: FYI, I was not using those properties in a general way (I'm quite aware that non-regularity is not closed for these in general), but it was unjustified and thinking about it shortly I don't see how to finish the proof in that manner.

Comment: I'm not questioning your intuition, only your proof -- your intuition that L(T) is all strings with the same number of 0s and 1s is correct.  Hint: what is relationship between the numbers of 0s and 1s in L(S)?  Can you apply the pumping lemma to L(S) using (almost) the same w you did for T?  Can you apply the pumping lemma directly to the grammar of T/S rather than the intuitionistic definition?

Comment: Ah, yes, L(S) is the language comprised of binary strings which contain at least as many 1s as 0s. And the proof of non-regularity is analogous to the one for L(T).